# VS2010 Entity Designer vs other 3rd party alternatives?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have been enjoying the VS2010 Entity Designer for Model-First DB modelling and generation. However I am finding it restrictive especially in terms of labelling associations and adding notes. My models will be large, and I plan to use multiple EDMX files for different parts of the model. The generated Classes will be used by an ASP.NET MVC project.

Model-First DB Migration is very important to me, which VS2012 does not support where the EF designer is much improved. The VS 2010 EF designer does not enable labelling etc so loss is information happens when you continue to normalise the model ie "Where are those columns now?" "Well they are records in that intersection table now."

I have been looking at alternative 3rd Party solutions that address this area more comprehensively. The first product I have come across is DevArt's Entity Developer.

I would appreciate any experience and advice on 3rd party solutions. It is a shame that I need to pull away from MS's VS EF offering.

Many thanks,

Ed